# How do I hide a parent div if the child div doesn't contain an <a> tag?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a parent div (i.e., #post) if the child div (i.e., .post-title) doesn't contain an `<a>` tag. Any insight in how to accomplish this correctly with the code I've modified?

```
<div id="latest">
    <div id="post">
        <div class="post-image post-image-1"></div>
        <div id="post-content">
            <div class="post-title post-title-1"></div>
            <div id="post-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="post">
        <div class="post-image post-image-2"></div>
        <div id="post-content">
            <div class="post-title post-title-2"></div>
            <div id="post-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.post-title').not($('a').hide($("#post"));
```

Comment: You cannot duplicate `id` values.

Comment: Use `$.fn.filter`

Comment: Use `has` function. https://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: Hey @PraveenKumar, none of these answers are working, but I think the reason why is because the <a> tag I'm referring to is being pulled in by another jQuery code on the site. The <a> tag wouldn't be added in the HTML manually, but instead via jQuery.

I'm modifying some of these great suggestions to see which one will work.

Comment: @greatwanderer but all the answers have a snippet that explains it right? Aren't they working as well? Did you see my snippet? Oh, you didn't say that. So you need to run the code after that injection has been done.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, sorry about that! I didn't think that information mattered. Yes, I tried your code and it worked just fine when I added the <a> tag into the HTML -- thank you for that -- however, when I removed the <a> tag from the HTML and relied on the jQuery code to pull in the <a> tag, the code you suggested no longer works.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, your code did not work the way you suggested it, but I modified it and got it to work:

$(function () {
  $(".post").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find("a").length != 0;
  }).hide();
});

However, the only reason this works is because I've dynamically added the <a> tag. I need it to work with the jQuery code that pulls in the <a> tag.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, all is not well -- a solution hasn't been found. I'm going to delete this and add in missing details.

Comment: @greatwanderer You shouldn't delete this because it is a disrespect to me and many of those people who answered this question. Leave it like this, it is a good one, people will be benefited.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, you got it! Thanks for all your help with this. =)

Comment: You accepted my answer then retracted? Why?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, while I really appreciate your contribution, it didn't work the way you had written it. Alex's code worked the way it was written.

Comment: @greatwanderer Thanks. Makes sense... `:)` But definitely you should go through all the comments on that answer... `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: dont use IDs mulitple times. Every ID should be unique :)

Secondly: `$('.post').not( ':has(".post-title a")' ).addClass('hide')`

Comment: This does the exact opposite. How does this even got a vote up?

Comment: @PraveenKumar updated :D wanted to be hipster and not use filter then... a little inperformant but the other answers do the trick anyways

Comment: Mate? Even this is wrong! `:P` It should not be hidden here, but the otherwise.

Comment: LoL. No. Expecting more from you. Make it right answer at least. `:D`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, @Alex! Simple and effective.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I feel deeply sorry :) but were not doing it for the rep, were doing it for honor, arent we? :)

Comment: @Alex When did I say, I was not happy. I motivated you to write the right answer and it won! So I am happy! `:D` Technically your answer is my answer. Ha ha ha.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Im just sorry because your answer was correct in the first place :D never mind, keep up the great work :)

Comment: @Alex It happens all the time buddy. Ultimately, it is the OP's decision to choose the correct one right? I asked it as well, and the OP gave me a convincing answer. `:D`

Answer (score 5):

> **Note:** It's a crime to duplicate the `id`s.

Making it right, by changing all the `id` dupes to `class` and this should work:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".post-title").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find("a").length == 0;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="latest">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-image post-image-1"></div>
    <div class="post-content">
      <div class="post-title post-title-1">Hide This</div>
      <div class="post-date"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-image post-image-2"></div>
    <div class="post-content">
      <div class="post-title post-title-2"><a href="">Don't Hide</a></div>
      <div class="post-date"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use jQuery's [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Like so:

```
$('.post-title').filter(function(i) { return !$(this).find('a').length }).hide();
```

### See example below

```js
$('.post-title').filter(function(i) { return !$(this).find('a').length }).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="latest">
    <div id="post">
        <div class="post-image post-image-1"></div>
        <div id="post-content">
            <div class="post-title post-title-1"><a href="javascript:void">Link here</a></div>
            <div id="post-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="post">
        <div class="post-image post-image-2"></div>
        <div id="post-content">
            <div class="post-title post-title-2">NO LINK</div>
            <div id="post-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="latest">
    <div id="post">
        <div class="post-image post-image-1"></div>
        <div id="post-content">
            <div class="post-title post-title-1">NO LINK</div>
            <div id="post-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="post">
        <div class="post-image post-image-2"></div>
        <div id="post-content">
            <div class="post-title post-title-2"><a href="javascript:void">Link here</a></div>
            <div id="post-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) using a boolean from checking the length of the children:

```
/* Loop Through Parents */
$('#post').each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).children('a').length > 0);
});
```